# How to access row from DBF table?

Tags: python, data, dbf

I have got the following problem:
I would like to access a row from a DBF table. I have tried to access it through SearchCursor, but I am not able to do it without knowing the field name. This is my code:

```
# Create SearchCursor
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("tabulka.gdb\zrazkove_uhrny")

# Get names of all fields
field_names = []
sFields=arcpy.ListFields("tabulka.gdb\zrazkove_uhrny")
for field in sFields:
    field_names.append(field.name)

# Print all values of second row
for row in rows:
    print row.field_names[1]
```

This code works only if I know the name of a row which I don't. I don't even know the number of columns in the table. This code work only if I substitute `row.field_names[1]` with `row.F2` (F2 is the name of the column).

**My questions are:**

1. Is there a simpler way how to access values in DBF table?
2. Is there a way how to access values in DBF table using SearchCursor and without knowing field (column) names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are approching this wrong.  By doing `row.field_names[1]` you are asking python to give you the `field_names` method on the `row` object which there isn't one.

Try this:

```
field = arcpy.ListFields("tabulka.gdb\zrazkove_uhrny")[1]
name = field.name
for row in rows:
    print row.getValue(name)
```

I think you might even be able to do `row.getValue(1)` but I'm not sure as I don't have arcpy on hand. Any Arcpy experts want to confirm or deny that?

Comment: Ok thank you. It helped. row.getValue(1) doesnt work, but it can be substituted with row.getValue(field_names[1]).

Thanks